# Powershell Start-Process command is not working in Windows EC2 instance when it is deployed from AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: powershell, aws-code-deploy

Below Powershell command working fine when I run this command directly in Windows EC2 server using powershell ISE. i.e., new cmd window is opened as expected

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\CodeDeploy\DeployCode.bat -Verb Runas
```

But when I run this same command through AWS CodeDeploy as below, I don't see any new cmd window being opened in Windows EC2 instance even though AWS CodeDeploy deployment is successful.

appspec.yml file

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: ./CodeDeploy
    destination: C:\CodeDeploy
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/postinstall-batchfile.ps1
      timeout: 300
      runas: Administrator
```

Note: Above Start-Process command placed in "Scripts/postinstall-batchfile.ps1" folder path. AWS codedeploy process is triggered by Jenkins job.

Thoughts on deploying this .bat file using Powershell script via AWS CodeDeploy process?

Comment: `Scripts/postinstall-batchfile.ps1`, which should more correctly probably be `Scripts\postinstall-batchfile.ps1`, _(because Windows separates paths with backward slashes)_, is relative to the current working directory. Usually when you Run as administrator, the current working directory becomes `C:\Windows\System32`, so your code should either use the full path to the batch file, or definitively change the current working directory to the one you intended it to be.

Comment: Scripts/postinstall-batchfile.ps1 - this location refers S3 bucket folder path where this ps file is resided. Yes, I've mentioned full batch as C:\CodeDeploy\DeployCode.bat in powershell script file.